# VS Code Error: command 'sftp.remoteExplorer.refresh' already exists

Tags: visual-studio-code

Почему может отвалиться редактирование файлов по sftp в VS Code?

В ошибке пишет, что нет конфига, но он есть, я его добавил, и, главное, сервер открывается, файлы видны, но после нажатия "Edit in local" вылетает ошибка...

```
[2023-05-16 15:50:02] [info] .env not exists
[2023-05-16 15:50:02] [info] config at d:\WORK\PHP_STORM_PRJ\dev.site.ru {"remotePath":"/","uploadOnSave":false,"ignoreRealPath":false,"useTempFile":false,"openSsh":false,"downloadOnOpen":false,"ignore":[],"concurrency":4,"protocol":"sftp","connectTimeout":10000,"interactiveAuth":false,"secure":false,"remoteTimeOffsetInHours":0,"remoteExplorer":{"order":0},"name":"dev.site.ru","host":"37.56.188.42","port":22,"username":"******","password":"******"}
[2023-05-16 15:50:02] [error] Error: command 'sftp.remoteExplorer.refresh' already exists
    at e.ExtHostCommands.registerCommand (c:\Users\toorr2p\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:98:123788)
    at Object.registerCommand (c:\Users\toorr2p\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:116:23226)
    at t.registerCommand (c:\Users\toorr2p\.vscode\extensions\satiromarra.code-sftp-1.18.0\dist\extension.js:2:401816)
    at new t.default (c:\Users\toorr2p\.vscode\extensions\satiromarra.code-sftp-1.18.0\dist\extension.js:2:415738)
    at c:\Users\toorr2p\.vscode\extensions\satiromarra.code-sftp-1.18.0\dist\extension.js:2:375468
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at o (c:\Users\toorr2p\.vscode\extensions\satiromarra.code-sftp-1.18.0\dist\extension.js:2:374553) 
[2023-05-16 15:55:22] [warn] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\toorr2p\.ssh\config' load C:\Users\toorr2p\.ssh\config failed
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]